# Django - Save Cloudinary Object via Upload Widget

Tags: django, cloudinary

I am trying to set up Cloudinary's upload widget and save the resulting Cloudinary objet to my `CloudinaryField()` on my model. Cloudinary's [sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-django-sample/blob/master/photo_album/templates/upload.html) only shows how to upload images using `{{form}}`.

When I upload using the widget, I get a dictionary back, but I can't find any place in the docs where it gives me a way to save it.

Comment: By "dictionary", did you mean the identifier string that's the value of the generated hidden input field, or the JSON response that's returned by the POST request?

Comment: It's the set of values returned by the POST request to Cloudinary. I suppose it is JSON, but I am sending it straight to the backend and Python seems to be recognizing it as a dictionary. Maybe I am skipping a step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upload widget has the option to include a notification URL and that can be configured in your upload preset settings. This notification URL will return a response to your server endpoint that can be used to save the image model.

To generate the necessary CloudinaryField from the upload response, a CloudinaryResource object can be used.

```
from cloudinary import CloudinaryResource

. . .

json_response = { "public_id": "test", "type": "upload", . . . }

# Populate a CloudinaryResource object using the upload response
result = CloudinaryResource(public_id=json_response['public_id'], type=json_response['type'], resource_type=json_response['resource_type'], version=json_response['version'], format=json_response['format'])

str_result = result.get_prep_value()  # returns a CloudinaryField string e.g. "image/upload/v123456789/test.png" 

# Save the result
p = Photo(title="title",image=str_result)
p.save()  # save result in database
```